# CSS Image overlay on hover with fade in

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

I've been trying to create the following: Showing an image and when hovering over it, on the image a score will show, which fades in. I'm almost there, except for the fading in part.

My CSS:

```css
.profile-image10 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.profile-image10:hover .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 510px;
  top: 8px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: transparent url('http://www.defilmkijker.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/overlayscore10.png') no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-image10">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg" /></a>
  <span class="overlay"></span>
</div>
```

I've created this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1wusom4m/

As you can see it currently fades out when hovering, which is the opposite of what I want. So of course the opacity is set the wrong way around, but if I set it to a low value in the .profile-image10 it affects the original image as well. I'm quite new to this, so have been experimenting a lot to get this far, but I'm stuck now. So how can I make it fade in the score when hovering over the image? Or am I approaching this all wrong?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1wusom4m/3/

Answer (score 0):

Three things.

1. Don't depend all style properties for your overlay on `:hover` state. Only those you want to change on `:hover` of the image.
2. Always define the `transition` property for the original state. You can change the *reverse* transition by additionally specifying it on the `:hover` state.
3. You `div` is a block level element, which by default grabs as much horizontal space as available. Putting the `:hover` on the `div` results in the fade effect being triggered even if you hover right of the picture (which probably is unwanted).

```css
.profile-image10 .overlay{
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 585px;
  top: 8px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: transparent url('http://www.defilmkijker.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/overlayscore10.png') no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}

.profile-image10 a:hover + .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-image10">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.defilmkijker.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Recensie-Three-Billboards-Outside-Ebbing-Missouri.jpg" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-19857 round" /></a>
  <span class="overlay"></span>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1wusom4m/3/

Comment: Thanks for that and it works exactly as I want to in fiddle. I've changed the code on my Wordpress site as well (and added the HTML to one of the posts), but there it doesn't seem to function. You can see it here: http://www.defilmkijker.com/2018/01/17/three-billboards-outside-ebbing-missouri-2017-recensie/